# Avoiding Content-Length in unirest request header

Tags: node.js, unirest

Here is my code

```
unirest.post(url)
      .headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
      .auth(this.auth)
      .timeout(global.timeout)
      .send({
        'username': this.username,
        'token': this.token
      });
```

It always generate `content-length` header. How to avoid unirest set content-length header automatically?

Answer (score 0):

content-length header is need to keep persistence of HTTP connection.
So it's better to keep setting it automatically.
Also unirest doesn't have any option to set content-length manually.

Comment: But I need to disable it, is there any other library that can disable it?

Comment: No there is no way to disable it. it's default by HTTP 1.1 standard.